# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable in equation

Tags: python, typeerror

This is my fourth python script, so please bear with my newbieness... I am writing a script that tells the day of week on a certain date.  It all runs fine except one error.  I have a faint idea as to what is wrong, but am not too certain:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, string

# Call example:  day_of_week(2,10,1988); February 10, 1988
def day_of_week(month, date, year):
    # January
    if month == 1: m = 11
    # February
    elif month == 2: m = 12
    # March
    elif month == 3: m = 1
    # April
    elif month == 4: m = 2
    # May
    elif month == 5: m = 3
    # June
    elif month == 6: m = 4
    # July
    elif month == 7: m = 5
    # August
    elif month == 8: m = 6
    # September
    elif month == 9: m = 7
    # October
    elif month == 10: m = 8
    # November
    elif month == 11: m = 9
    # December
    elif month == 12: m = 10

    # Calculate the day of the week
    dow = (date + ((13 * m-1)/5) + year[2:] + (year[2:]/4) + (year[:2]/4) - 2 * year[:2]) % 7)

    # Formatting!
    if dow == 0: return "Sunday"
    elif dow == 1: return "Monday"
    elif dow == 2: return "Tuesday"
    elif dow == 3: return "Wednesday"
    elif dow == 4: return "Thursday"
    elif dow == 5: return "Friday"
    elif dow == 6: return "Saturday"
    else: return "Error!"

try:
    m = int(raw_input("What month were you born in (1-12)?  "))
    if not 1 <= m <= 12: raise Exception("There are no months with a number higher than 12!")
    d = int(raw_input("On what date were you born on?  "))
    y = int(raw_input("What year were you born in?  "))
    print("\nYou were born on a %s!" % day_of_week(m,d,y))
except ValueError:
    print("You need to enter a number!")
```

Comment: Do you need to use `str()` before slicing?

Comment: Unrelated to the code, but python has a standard library module for calendar functionality [calendar docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/calendar.html).

Comment: You can use the following snippet to check your results: `from datetime import date; d = date(2007, 9, 23); '{0:%A}'.format(d) # 'Sunday'`

Comment: @JonClements Ha, I need to start keeping track of all the cool code snippets you come up with :)

Comment: Tips: The `elif` chains are pretty laboured. In general could consider using dictionaries to map values instead. However the first one could be avoided by subtracting 2 and using modulo operator: `m = (month - 2) % 12`

Answer (score 3):

In this line:

```
dow = (date + ((13 * m-1)/5) + year[2:] + (year[2:]/4) + (year[:2]/4) - 2 * year[:2]) % 7)
```

You are using `year` (an integer) and trying to return a slice from it. As the error indicates, `int` objects do not allow you to do this. In order to accomplish what you want, you would need to cast `year` as a string.

However an easier solution may be to use the built-in features of the `datetime` module to calculate the day of the week:

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: my_date = datetime.date(2012, 11, 26)

In [3]: my_date.weekday()
Out[3]: 0
```

This uses Monday as the starting date (0). To keep with your current code, you can use `isoweekday()`, where Monday = 1:

```
In [11]: import datetime

In [12]: my_date = datetime.date(2012, 11, 26)

In [13]: my_date.isoweekday()
Out[13]: 1
```

You can then use @JonClement's slick snippet above to return the string of the day:

```
In [14]: '{0:%A}'.format(my_date)
Out[14]: 'Monday'
```

Comment: You mean to tell me that this whole time what i was trying to do was already a built in function?  :(  Thanks so much anyway <3

Comment: @AlexanderGardner Ha, don't worry - I can't even count the number of times I've done something complicated to solve something, and then found out there was a one-liner to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You must cast your `int` to a `string` first, with [`str()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) in order to slice it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't cast your int to a string; use arithmetic:

```
century = year / 100
lasttwo = year % 100
dow = (date + ((13 * m-1)/5) + lasttwo + (lasttwo/4) + (century/4) - 2 * century) % 7)
```

And because I'm physically incapable of resisting such challenges, I tried to make the rest of the code a little more Pythonic:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""Calculate the day of the week of dates"""


def day_of_week(month, day, year):
    """Return the name of the weekday of the given date

    >>> day_of_week(1, 1, 1970)
    'Friday'
    >>> day_of_week(11, 26, 2012)
    'Monday'
    """
    moff = (month + 9) % 12 + 1

    # Calculate the day of the week
    century = year / 100
    lasttwo = year % 100
    dow = (day + (13 * moff - 1) / 5 + lasttwo + lasttwo / 4 + century / 4
        - 2 * century) % 7

    # Formatting!
    return ("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday",
        "Saturday")[dow]


def main():
    """Test the program, then run it interactively"""
    import doctest
    testresult = doctest.testmod()
    if testresult.failed:
        import sys
        sys.exit(1)
    try:
        month = int(raw_input("What month were you born in (1-12)?  "))
        if not 1 <= month <= 12:
            raise Exception("Month must be between 1 and 12!")
        day = int(raw_input("On what date were you born on?  "))
        year = int(raw_input("What year were you born in?  "))
        print("\nYou were born on a %s!" % day_of_week(month, day, year))
    except ValueError:
        print("You need to enter a number!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Notice that the actual logic is identical to your version. It just uses code that's a bit simpler. I presume that your end goal is more about learning Python than it is actually performing this calculation. If I'm wrong, scratch all of the above and use the `datetime` module which is far simpler still.

Comment: Tests included?! +1 to you! Agree this is more instructive than using `datetime`.