# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable (from pause function)

Tags: python, pyscripter

This is what I believe is the relevant part of my code:

```
def choose_From_Inventory(itemType):

    global inventory
    string=""
    """sets up how people choose items from inventory"""
    for i in range(len(inventory)):
        if inventory[i][0]==itemType:
            string=string+"["+str(i)+"]: "+inventory[i][4]+"\n"
    return string
```

This returns the error on the if statement.

This happens whenever I call this function:

```
def pauseScreen():

    global hp, inventory, level, location, sq1, sq2, sq3, sq4
    """prints the pause screen, lets them see hp, inventory, and location"""
    print("\t\t HP:\n\t\t",hp,"\n\t\tInventory:\n"+str(choose_From_Inventory(0))+"\n"+str(choose_From_Inventory(1))+"\n"+str(choose_From_Inventory(2))+"\n"+str(choose_From_Inventory(3))+"\n\t\tLevel (Location):\n\t\t",level,location)
    returnCode=input("Press enter to return or type in quit to quit\n")
    if returnCode.lower()=='quit':
        quit=input("Are you sure?\n")
        if quit.lower()=='yes':
            sys.exit()
        else:
            pauseScreen()
    else:
        levelCheck()
```

This doesn't happen every time, but I haven't been able to figure out why it doesn't work. I've tried several other ways to format the if statement, but I was hoping someone would be able to help me here.

Also, I did check several other questions with similar titles, such as this one ([TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089020/typeerror-int-object-is-not-subscriptable)) and this one ([TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable in equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575411/typeerror-int-object-is-not-subscriptable-in-equation))
They didn't help me find a solution.

Thanks!

~Wpx

Comment: You haven't shown what `inventory` is, but it seems to be a list of ints, rather than a list of whatever you think it is. Also note that any time you find yourself iterating over `range(len(something))` in Python, you're doing it wrong; iterate over the thing itself.

Comment: Inventory is a 2D and 3D list, with the 2D for most of them having 4 ints and 1 string, and the 3D part replacing one of the ints with 2 ints within more brackets (eg. [[0,0,10,4,"example"],[0,0,[5,0],5,"example2"]])              For the range(len(something)) what that is doing is the for statement for each item in the list. What part of that should I change?

Comment: `inventory` probably has some items that arent nested lists, so getting `inventory[i]` would return an int rather than a dict or list as you seem to expect

Comment: I just double checked, and inventory doesn't have any lone items (as in, something not within another list, which is what I understand from what you said).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright...I was working with a friend, and he found the error. It was in how I was adding an item to the inventory.

Thanks to those who read this, and especially those who tried to find the error.

~Wpx